# Qgis 3.12 - Add part tool is missing

Tags: qgis

I have Qgis 3.12 and I want to add a part to a polygon but there is no add part button?

I enable advanced digitising tools but I get error: cad tools cannot be used on geographic co-ordinates.

How do I enable this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find you've tried to enable the Advanced Digitizing *Panel* (which is the CAD Tools plugin), not the Advanced Digitizing *Toolbar*.

Right-click on an empty toolbar area. There should be a list of Panels at the top and Toolbars below it.